# when i use a method in other class it returns a nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android

Ok, so im currently working on a app that gives memes, its a project for my own learning but im really stuck at one point from 4 days and this error is just a small part of it... so now i have created a method in afragment called Explore Fragment and i have created a switch in mainactivity which changes the fragment when a particular button in bottom navigation is clicked, so there i call this method when the user clicks on explore tab, but when i click on explore tab the app crashes and returns 2 errors. errors are -

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.example.memeit.ExploreFragment$2.onResponse(ExploreFragment.java:148)
at com.example.memeit.ExploreFragment$2.onResponse(ExploreFragment.java:136)

line 148 -  list.add(class_object);

line 136 - JsonObjectRequest response = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener()

please help

Main Activity -

```
package com.example.memeit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomnavigation;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    ArrayList<exploreclass> list;
    public RecyclerView rcv1_explore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new HomeFragment());
        transaction.commit();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        bottomnavigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        rcv1_explore =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcv_explore);
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        bottomnavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull MenuItem item) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.home :
                        transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new HomeFragment());
                        break;

                    case R.id.explore:
                        transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new ExploreFragment());
                        ExploreFragment exploreFragment = new ExploreFragment();
                        exploreFragment.ExtractMemes(getApplicationContext(), "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/30");
                        break;

                    case R.id.saved:
                        transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new SavedFragment());
                        break;

                    case R.id.settings:
                        transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, new SettingsFragment());
                        break;
                }
                transaction.commit();

                return true;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Explore Fragment -

```
package com.example.memeit;

import static com.android.volley.VolleyLog.TAG;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link ExploreFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ExploreFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    public String BASEURL = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/30";
    public TextView tv1_likes;
    public RecyclerView rcv1_explore;
    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<exploreclass> list;
    public boolean isScrolling = false;
    public int currentItems, totalItems, scrolledOutItems;
    public LinearLayoutManager manager;
    public explore_adapter adapter;

    public ExploreFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ExploreFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ExploreFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ExploreFragment fragment = new ExploreFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container, false);
        tv1_likes =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1_explore);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        rcv1_explore =(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rcv_explore);
        rcv1_explore.setHasFixedSize(true);

        rcv1_explore.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
                currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
                scrolledOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();


                if(isScrolling && (totalItems == currentItems + scrolledOutItems)) {
                    isScrolling = false;
                    fetchMoreData();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    public void ExtractMemes(Context context, String url) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JsonObjectRequest response = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray memes_array = response.getJSONArray("memes");
                    for(int i=0; i<memes_array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject memes_object = memes_array.getJSONObject(i);

                        exploreclass class_object = new exploreclass();
                        class_object.setUps(memes_object.getInt("ups"));
                        class_object.setUrl(memes_object.getString("url"));
                        class_object.setPostLink(memes_object.getString("postLink"));
                        list.add(class_object);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                explore_adapter adapter = new explore_adapter(list, getContext());
                rcv1_explore.setLayoutManager(manager);
                rcv1_explore.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        queue.add(response);

    }



    private void fetchMoreData() {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        JsonObjectRequest response = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, BASEURL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONArray memes_array = response.getJSONArray("memes");
                    for(int i=0; i<memes_array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject memes_object = memes_array.getJSONObject(i);

                        exploreclass class_object = new exploreclass();
                        class_object.setUps(memes_object.getInt("ups"));
                        class_object.setUrl(memes_object.getString("url"));
                        class_object.setPostLink(memes_object.getString("postLink"));
                        list.add(class_object);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        queue.add(response);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `list` is not initialized when you call the method `ExtractMemes` so the object is null.

The method is called before the `onCreateView`

Try to init it at the declaration.

**Edit :**

In first case, you are initializing the fragment twice and use the method in the instance who is not send to the FragmentTransaction.
Here a correct way :

```
case R.id.explore:
        ExploreFragment exploreFragment = new ExploreFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, exploreFragment);
        exploreFragment.ExtractMemes(getApplicationContext(), "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/30");
        break;
```

Then, in `ExtractMemes` method, you are using `list` who is initialized in `OnCreatView`.

But, the createView is called after the `transaction.commit()`.
You have to init `list` at the declaration or at the creation of the Fragment.

Comment: Sorry I'm not so good at android, i didn't understood your response, you said that the method is called before onCreateView, but the method is called in the switch statement after on create, so I didn't understood what you meant? Also you said I have to initialize it, so that means I should initialize it in the switch case 2 statement?

Comment: I just edited my answer.